# Loader-GIF doesn't move when AJAX is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, animated-gif

I'm trying to make a GIF-loader, which will be shown as long as my AJAX request is being processed.  I'm using the [jquery loader plugin](https://github.com/mimiz/jquery-loader-plugin).

The problem is, the GIF doesn't move when the browser is busy processing the AJAX request, though it is moving, when setting it to `visible` for testing purposes.
I've tested it in 3 major browsers.

This is an extract of my code. The real code is, of course, much more complex:

```
  $("#myButton").click(function() {
    $.loader({
      className: "blue-with-image-2",
      content: ''
    });

    getData();
  });

  function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",

      success: function(data) {
        // do something with data
        console.log(data)
        $.loader('close'); // close the loader
      },
      error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
        console.error(status, error);
      }
    });
  }
```

[Here is a fiddle with that example code](https://jsfiddle.net/5smzorcu/).

The funny thing is, when testing this particular code in jsFiddle, **it does 
work**. But **not my real code**, which is almost the same, but just more complex.

Comment: The syptoms you describe sound like the request is being made synchronously and blocking the UI from being updated. Have you set `async: false` in a global AJAX setup?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: No, the only thing I deactivated is the cache.

Answer (score 0):

Use function 'beforeSend' in ajax call

```
function getData() {
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos",
  beforeSend: function() {
      $('#response').html("<img src='/images/loading.gif' />");
  },
  success: function(data) {
    // do something with data
    console.log(data)
    $.loader('close'); // close the loader
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
    console.error(status, error);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it didn't solve the problem.